# No re-entry not available as choice for Contact Entry journey setting

Tags: marketing-cloud

We found out that the Contact Entry setting of our version 1 of a journey has erroneously been set to "Re-entry only after exiting".

Pausing the journey and trying to change the setting is not possible.

So we created a version 2 and tried to change the setting. However, the option that we would like to use is not permitted:

[image]

Why not? And what must we do to change it to "No re-entry"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change this you have to copy the journey (or make a new one), you can't make changes to this configuration in a journey

[Journey Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5)

> This setting applies across all versions of a journey. After you activate the journey, you can’t change this option.

Comment: I overlooked that. This really sucks, versions of a journey deal with contacts in the old and current version elegantly. If I copy the journey, I must somehow deal with this myself :-( Thanks anyway!